# C++ multiple conditions for if statement

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

How am I supposed to put in multiple conditions to be met?

```
    else if (studentoverall < 90; studentoverall>=80)
    {
        lettergrade = "B";
    }
```

Comment: Have you *ever* seen that ";" syntax in *any* book?  What made you think it *would* work?  The answer is to use the ["AND"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6s3h5a7.aspx) operator: `else if ((studentoverall < 90) && (studentoverall>=80)) { ... }`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that since c++ 17 you can declare a variable in the if condition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836867/c-variable-declaration-in-if-expression It is unrelated to `&&` however, the main use case is to calculate ant return truthy/falsy things with `auto`.

Answer (score 16):

With [Logical AND (`&&`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators):

```
else if (studentoverall < 90 && studentoverall >= 80)
```