# I got an infinite while loop with this string

Tags: c++, while-loop

so I got this part of my code here:

```
string stringparam;

string stringparam1;

double d;

unsigned x;


cout << "Welcome" << endl;

cout << "Choose one (ASUS, MSI, Gigabyte, ASrock)" << endl;
cin >> stringparam;
while (stringparam != "ASUS" || "MSI" || "Gigabyte" || "ASrock")
{
    cout << "you gave bad input \n" << endl;
    cout << "Choose one (ASUS, MSI, Gigabyte, ASrock)" << endl;
    cin >> stringparam;
}
```

the problem is even if I give him a correct answer like "ASUS" it still gives me the error message  : "you gave bad input"
What can i do about it?

Comment: `stringparam != "ASUS" || "MSI" || "Gigabyte" || "ASrock"` doesn’t do what you think it does. It’s the same as `(stringparam != "ASUS") || "MSI" || "Gigabyte" || "ASrock"`, and `"MSI"` will always be true. You want `stringparam != "ASUS" && stringparam != "MSI" && ...`.

Comment: Just blindly guessing syntax never works. Learn what `stringparam != "ASUS" || "MSI" || "Gigabyte" || "ASrock"` really means by reading about the operators.

Comment: thats the closest I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144294/c-multiple-conditions-for-if-statement. Your condition is: "(stringparam is not "ASUS") or ("MSI") or ..." not "stringparam is not ("ASUS" or "MSI" or ...)"

Comment: `or` is the wrong operator anyway, even if you fix the more obvious problem of not comparing the string. A logical or is very different from the `or` as used in a natural spoken languange.

Comment: thanks for the fast response guys I will try to look around a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the main problem is that you can't do what you want with "or" operator, because in that way while condition it will always be True.

For example:
if you type "ASUS", the result of while is True, this because you need ONLY one || expression = True to "come in" while's body (this caused infinite loop).

So you have to use "&" operator. With this, all condition MUST be True to execute while's body.

```
while (stringparam != "ASUS" && "MSI" && "Gigabyte" && "ASrock")
```

Alternatively, you can use the do/while loop:

```
do{
    cout << "you gave bad input \n" << endl;
    cout << "Choose one (ASUS, MSI, Gigabyte, ASrock)" << endl;
    cin >> stringparam;
}while(stringparam != "ASUS" && stringparam != "MSI" && ...);
```

Comment: it's working now thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome! Have a good day! :)

Comment: `cout << cout << ..` compiles?

Comment: @AndreaMaestrutti Good that you're taking it the right way. More often than not, such comments are completely without any bad intent. But I think this answer should be improved further. You're making the do-while the central thing, but that's not really related to the problem. It's just an improvement. But you don't explain anything what's done to actually solve the problem.

Comment: @AndreaMaestrutti I removed my downvote because you reacted so well. Correct the issues I mentioned and have an upvote. ;)

Comment: Ok thanks for suggestion, and sorry for the bad answer ;) but this morning i was at work with some bugs in the code, and that made me so nervous...

Answer (score 5):

Just blindly guessing syntax never works. I recommend learning what `stringparam != "ASUS" || "MSI" || "Gigabyte" || "ASrock"` really means by reading about the operators.

You could do something like this to achieve what you want in a quite neat way. It requires C++11 or later.

```
std::set<std::string> ss = {"ASUS","MSI" , "Gigabyte","ASrock" };

while(ss.find(stringparam) == ss.end()) {
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes,your code goes in infinite loop
Because ,your have used string with OR operator.
And in C++ anything except O, null, empty string is positive.
So,your while loop condition is always true.
That's why your code goes in infinite loop.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong. Assuming that `O == 0`, and an empty string is also a string which would return true. What you probably meant is using `string.empty()` which is rather different.