# Can't check return value of a function in C

Tags: c, function

So I'm trying to check my functions return value in an if statement so that i can check wheter it's working fine or not.

I have:

```
    if (int r = (input(num_first, num_second, fixPTR)) =! -1)
    {
// do smth
    }
```

but Visual Studio says : expression must be a modifiable lvalue

how do i fix it??

Comment: You cannot declare a variable in an `if` controlling expression.

Comment: Declare `r` outside the `if`.

Comment: Check your basic C syntax. `!-1` is always `0` and is valid, but I doubt that's what you intended to check for.

Comment: @Quentin show me a valid declaration in an `if` controlling expression and I show you you are wrong.

Comment: @Quentin This may be a subtle difference between C and C++. I believe the (informal) C grammar does not allow for declarations, but the C++ one appears to (cf. Mike's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836867/c-variable-declaration-in-if-expression).

Comment: I'm writing C code in Visual C++ so i can declare variables in an if statement.

Comment: @ouah My bad ! I did mix up with C++. Looks like I'm not the only one :)

Comment: Not sure what you are intending to do, but i believe the != operator has a higher precedence than the = operator, so 'return value' != -1 will evaluate to true or false and t hen be assigned to 'int r'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare your variables before your code.

And the syntax for the opposite of `==` is `!=` and not `=!` by the way.

```
int r;

if ((r = input(num_first, num_second, fixPTR)) != -1)
{
// do smth
}
```