# Wrong code structure accepted by GCC/G++

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

Using the GCC/G++ compiler, I've used the following code structure for a long time and never had any problem with it:

```
if((int returnCode = function(argument1, argument2)) != 0) {
    manageTheError(returnCode);
}
```

I switched to Visual C++ 2015, but now my code throws many errors everytime I use this structure: (translated from french)

```
Syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'returnCode' (line 1)
'returnCode': undeclared identifier (line 1)
Syntax error: '!=' (line 1)
Syntax error: ')' (line 1)
Syntax error: missing ';' before '{' (line 1)
')' was expected (line 1)
expression was expected (line 1)
'returnCode': undeclared identifier (line 2)
identifier 'returnCode' undefined (line 2)
```

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836867/c-variable-declaration-in-if-expression) explains, my code structure is wrong and should not be used. But why does GCC/G++ accept it without complaining (not even a warning) and how does it manage these structures?

Comment: You may replace if's condition with `if(int returnCode = function(argument1, argument2))`, since it is equivalent form, that is valid in C++ and it's working in VS2013.

Comment: _"Never had any problem with it"_ [I do believe you're making that up](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/986c4955d2473c82).

Comment: Well in code::blocks it doesn't throw an error...

Comment: Don't tag questions as *both* C and C++ unless it really is.  This is a C++ question if you're using MS C++ and G++.

Comment: `if(x)` is defined as equivalent to `if( x != 0 )` so (as Grzegorz noted already) you can solve your problem by just taking out the `!= 0`.