# auto assignment in if clause

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have code below and it reports "auto is not allowed here"

```
//GeSettings() returns boost::optional<ValueType> and could be empty

if((auto ret = GetSettings(InputField)) && ShouldWeDoThis())
{
   do something with ret;
}
```

but changing as below if fine.

```
if(auto ret = GetSettings(InputField))
{
    if(ShouldWeDoThis())
    {
        do something with ret;
    }
}
```

The reason behind could be silly buy may I ask why? I am using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2017, do you use the new C++17 features? Or are you restricted to C++14?

Comment: @DeiDei good point, it's actually still 2013 compiler, pushed to upgrade to 2017

Comment: C++17 allows `if (auto ret = GetSettings(InputField); ret && ShouldWeDoThis())`.

Comment: Once you have that, the idiomatic way to handle this is with `if (auto ret = GetSettings(InputField); ret && ShouldWeDoThis()) { do something with ret; }`. This initialization is allowed in `if` and `switch`, and is analogous to the initialization section of a `for` loop. Note that the value of `ret` isn’t necessarily checked in the `if` statement; you still need to do that yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++, variable declaration in 'if' expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836867/c-variable-declaration-in-if-expression)

Answer (score 7):

Your first version:

```
if((auto ret = GetSettings(InputField)) && ShouldWeDoThis())
```

is not allowed under any c++ standard, as you can not have declarations in expressions.

§6.4 (from c++11) Selection statements defines what an if statement looks like:

> - if (condition) statement
> - if (condition) statement else statement

Further down condition is defined:

> - expression
> - attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq declarator = initializer-clause
> - attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq declarator braced-init-list

This allows us to write things like

```
if (auto ret = Foo())
```

However, in c++17 and forward, the definition changed (and moved to §9.4):

> - if constexpr<sub>opt</sub> (init-statement<sub>opt</sub> condition) statement
> - if constexpr<sub>opt</sub> (init-statement<sub>opt</sub> condition) statement else statement

We can now write things like:

```
if (auto ret=Foo(); ret && Bar())
```

Which should be useful for your purpose.

Comment: And to extend the answer a bit, it's possible to do more than one init-statement: `if (auto stream = wstream.lock(); auto delegate = stream->_delegate.lock())`. I.e. useful when dealing with multiple `std::weak_ptr`s that need to be locked in order to execute the conditional block.