# An error related to assignment within an if-statement condition

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, assignment-operator, auto

What could be wrong with this construct?

```
    if((auto idx = diff * 2) <= objRef.size()){


          //do something
}
```

where diff is of type ptrdiff_t and objRef is of type std::vector.

The following compiler errors are generated for the above statement:

```
   1 In file included from main.cpp:1:
   2 ./bt.hpp:597:28: error: expected ')'
   3                   i
   4                   if((auto idx = diff * 2) <= objRef.size())
   5 f((auto idx = diff * 2) <= objRef.size())
   6                            ^
   7 ./bt.hpp:597:22: note: to match this '('
   8                   if((auto idx = diff * 2) <= objRef.size())
   9                      ^
  10 ./bt.hpp:597:44: error: expected expression
  11                   if((auto idx = diff * 2) <= objRef.size())
  12                                            ^
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++, variable declaration in 'if' expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836867/c-variable-declaration-in-if-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7837092/159145 the contents of an `if` statement condition must be either an *expression* or a *single-variable-declaration*.

In your case, `auto idx = diff * 2` is a single-variable-declaration, but because you combined it with `<= objRef.size()` the `if`'s condition then ceases to be a *single-variable-declaration*, but it isn't an *expression* either because it includes a declaration - hence the compiler complains.

Change your code to compute `idx` before the `if` statement:

```
auto idx = diff * 2;
if( idx <= objRef.size() ) {

}
```

If you want to restrict the scope of `idx` then use an anonymous-scope:

```
{
    auto idx = diff * 2;
    if( idx <= objRef.size() ) {

    }
}
```

...or just elide the `auto idx` entirely, assuming you have no further use for it:

```
if( diff * 2 <= objRef.size() ) {

}
```

Comment: Note that C++20 will probably allow `if ( auto idx = diff * 2; idx <= objRef.size() )`, equivalent to your second suggestion.

Comment: @aschepler god, that looks ugly