# c++: Multiple assignment inside if block syntax for short circuiting

Tags: c++, short-circuiting

I wanted to be able to do multiple assignments in an if block and short-circuit if the first one fails. However, this does not compile and says, `expected primary-expression before ‘auto’`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> foo()
{
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    if (auto a = foo() && auto b = foo())
    {
        std::cout << "a = " << *a << ", b = " << *b << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The following works though and does what I want.

```cpp
    if (auto a = foo())
    {
      if (auto b = foo()) {
        std::cout << "a = " << *a << ", b = " << *b << std::endl;
      }
    }
```

But is there a way for me to use the syntax in the first one? Using parenthesis to surround the expressions does not work.

Comment: According to http://jatinganhotra.com/blog/2013/02/09/c-plus-plus-variable-declaration-in-if-expression/ the standard says we can only do one assignment in an expression

Comment: Just saw that there is an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7837092/9199167) in that other question, which addresses your issue as well.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't come across the fact that only a single variable declaration is allowed. Thank you.

Comment: @Mochan You can actually declare more than one variable now with C++17.  Those answers are outdated.

Comment: @NathanOliver How? I'm using g++ 8.30

Comment: @Mochan See my comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++17, you could write

```
if (decltype(foo()) a, b; (a = foo()) && (b = foo()))
{
    std::cout << "a = " << *a << ", b = " << *b << std::endl;
}
```

But if you want to see the short circuit in action, you should change the condition:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo called.\n";
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    if (decltype(foo()) a, b; (a = foo()) or (b = foo()))
    {
        // For exposition only            ^^
        std::cout << "a = " << *a << ", b = " << *b << std::endl;
        // Note that, now, this is UB            ^^
    }
}
```

Compare the output of [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dVbgVHCS15QMtQdc)

```
foo called.
a = 1, b = 0
```

Versus the [former](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0VVHzMdSRz7o7ezW).

Comment: Clever idea to use `decltype()` instead of `auto` .

Comment: Do note that `*b` is UB since `b` doesn't have a value.  You'll need to guard against uninitialized variables in the body, or assign them a default value to begin with.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, the OP correctly used `&&`. The `||` version is only to trigger the short circuit.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with `auto`. Declarations cannot be part of an expression. You can either use an expression or a single declaration inside an if statement.

So even this will not compile:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    if (int a = foo() && int b = foo())
    {
        std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** In C++17 you can have an initializer statement before the condition statement, like so: `if (auto a = foo(), b = foo(); a && b)`. However that will not give you short circuiting.

Comment: You can have more than a single declaration now.  `if (auto a = foo(), b = foo(); a && b)` is legal in C++17, but it doesn't stop `b` from being declared so `foo` is called twice.  Might be OK for the OP though.

Comment: @NathanOliver That works for me in gcc 8. Thank you.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I edited that in. Doesn't give OP the desired short circuiting, though.

Comment: What if a and b do not have the same type?

Comment: @MaxVollmer I didn't realize I don't get short-circuiting.

Comment: @Mochan They have to have the same type, or the same type but with reference or pointer qualifications.  It is the same thing as the init part of a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see is that you reformulate (without declaring the variables inside the `if` condition):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> foo()
{
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::optional<int> a , b;
    if ((a = foo()) && (b = foo()))
    {
        std::cout << "a = " << *a << ", b = " << *b << std::endl;
    }
}
```

See a working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0710a9840114956) please.

---

Since c++17 you can even do the variable declarations inside the `if` condition like this:

```
if (std::optional<int> a , b; (a = foo()) && (b = foo()))
```

Though usage of `auto` isn't possible in that case.

Another [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ee69409ba950ed2).