# auto in if clause - the way to define parameters inside if

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++14, auto

I want to define a parameter inside if . for example

```
if(MyDataPtr && auto* InfoPtr = MyDataPtr ->extractInfo())
```

And gen compilation error `Expected ')'`
Is it impossible? or what ca be done? - i don`t like the code bellow - looking for better (elegant) implementation

```
if(MyDataPtr)
{
   auto* InfoPtr = MyDataPtr ->extractInfo();
   if (InfoPtr )
     //some code
}
```

Comment: *" i don`t like the code bellow..."* Why? What does elegant mean here? Elegant means different things to different people. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836950/12002570) in the related/dupe: [C++, variable declaration in 'if' expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836867/c-variable-declaration-in-if-expression)

Comment: For a workaround see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7839226/12002570). Just split it in two different if statements. But I guess you already know that.

Comment: `if (auto* InfoPtr = MyDataPtr ? MyDataPtr->extractInfo() : nullptr)` for another alternative

Answer (score 4):

After C++ 17, you can do this:

```
if (T* InfoPtr; MyDataPtr && (InfoPtr = MyDataPtr->extractInfo()) {
    // use InfoPtr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't define variables in the middle of expressions. But you can define a variable as a single expression and use it as a condition, which will simplify your code a *little* bit:

```
if (MyDataPtr)
{
    if (auto InfoPtr = MyDataPtr->extractInfo())
    {
        // Use InfoPtr...
    }
}
```

Is it more "elegant"? To some perhaps.